# SQL Server : primary key usage and variable concatenation

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a single table and I have 2 unique columns. But the table does not have a primary key.

When I create a SQL connection with Visual Studio, I get an error

> Primary key does not exist

My question is: can I create a new column include PK and collect the contents of 2 columns and save in that new column?

Sample:

| Unique1 | Unique2 | New_PK_Column |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001234 | 0012 | 0012340012 |
| 646464 | 1010101 | 6464641010101 |
| 646464 | 1010102 | 6464641010102 |
| 646464 | 1010103 | 6464641010103 |
| 646465 | 1010101 | 6464651010101 |
| 646465 | 1010102 | 6464651010102 |

Comment: Is there any other purpose for adding a new column? If not, perhaps make the two columns the primary key.

Comment: It actually has a purpose. I forgot to write. More than one record will be entered from the same number. Sample:
1234-11
1234-12
1234-13
1235-11
1235-12
1235-13
..... As far as I know, PK has to be completely unique and non-repeatable.

Comment: But will the combination of the two columns always be unique? If so you can do something like this:

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[xxxxxx](
 [Unique1] [nchar](10) NOT NULL,
 [Unique2] [nchar](10) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_xxxxxx] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
 (
  [Unique1] ASC,
  [Unique2] ASC
 )
)

Comment: If both columns are each unique there's no point in making them a composite key, the "primary" key should be the column that is predominantly joined-to or filtered by; a composite key on both will only add unecessary overhead by including them both in any nonclustered index.

Comment: It sounds like the combination of both are unique, but each column may not be.

Comment: @BonzoFestoon that's not how I would interperet a sample column with the name "Unique1"

Comment: @Stu the OP commented that the combination will be unique, but each column may not be. The naming of the columns is not completely accurate.

Comment: that's correct. columns name just a sample. As I said above, more than one can be added from the same number (both columns are int).

Comment: *and collect the contents of 2 unique columns*... that should be *non*unique columns then

Comment: my apologize. edited.

Comment: Does it have to be a combination of the two values? That can get tricky with overflows and such during conversion.  What about a synthetic key based on an IDENTITY column for an int: [SyntheticIntKey] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL

Comment: There is no need to create a new column with the contents of two other columns. Just make your primary key a composite key of the two columns that make up the unique value for each row. Duplicating the data to a second column would be very problematic as you don't want the same data stored twice.

Comment: @BonzoFestoon This was the first thing that came to my mind, but when I told the employer, he did not accept it.

Comment: If both columns together guarantee uniqueness then absolutely you should define a composite primary key; what you almost certaintly should *not* do is create a new column and update it as the concatenation of these two existing columns to be a primary key - that would serve no purpose, lead to poor performance, data duplication and data discrepancies - what happens if after you created a concatenated value someone updated one of the values?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're going to do that only once and after that you are going to implement the system to start using the New_PK_Column.
First, what I would do is to check if the assumption of Unique1 + Unique2 is indeed unique with the below query.

```
SELECT Unique1, Unique2 FROM UniqueTable GROUP BY Unique1, Unique2 HAVING COUNT(1) > 1;
```

Then I would work around the results to understand what to do with them, if they're duplicates and remove them from the table entirely by deleting or updating it.

After cleansing, I would `ALTER` the `TABLE` to `ADD` the column. Important to set the `TYPE` with the size of both columns (if possible). I used the type `VARCHAR(14)` merely as example, **make sure to change it to your scenario**.

```
ALTER TABLE UniqueTable ADD New_PK_Column VARCHAR(14);
```

Update all rows concatenating the two columns

```
UPDATE UniqueTable SET New_PK_Column = Unique1+Unique2;
```

Alter the column to NOT NULL

```
ALTER TABLE UniqueTable ALTER COLUMN New_PK_Column VARCHAR(14) NOT NULL;
```

Add the primary key constraint

```
ALTER TABLE UniqueTable ADD PRIMARY KEY (New_PK_Column);
```

**Edit: IF the columns are INT**

The conversion should be done using leading zeros for this to work, because you could have the scenario below.

| Unique1 | Unique2 | New_PK_Column |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 1 | **111** *same values* |
| 1 | 11 | **111** *same values* |

Below is an example converting the integer to a string o 10 position each (since the max value of an integer is `2,147,483,647`) on the update before the `ALTER` ( the alter should use a field that can store the full length of the two integers concatenated) to `NOT NULL` should be like this:

```
UPDATE UniqueTable SET New_PK_Column = RIGHT('0000000000' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),Unique1),10)+RIGHT('0000000000' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),Unique1),10);
```

The results should look like that:

| Unique1 | Unique2 | New_PK_Column |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 12 | 00000012340000001234 |
| 646464 | 1010101 | 00006464640000646464 |
| 646464 | 1010102 | 00006464640000646464 |
| 646464 | 1010103 | 00006464640000646464 |
| 646465 | 1010101 | 00006464650000646465 |
| 646465 | 1010102 | 00006464650000646465 |

PS: I understand that this must be a requisite, but if not, why not use a composite Key for the primary key or creating a separate key with an identity. Food for thought and working around the problem. Regards.

PS2: If you do use this approach, it might be could to add a `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT` to prevent Unique1 and Unique2 diverge from the new column or not being unique.

Comment: Since the columns, Unique1 and Unique2, are ints, you are not concatenating in the update; you are adding.

Comment: O, didn't notice that it was stated it as an int in the comments, clouded my perception because there left zeros on the first row of the samples, and I assumed as a string.
That might cause other issues, that I'm going to note on my edit regarding combinations being able to be repeated among ints without fixed size convertions.

Comment: Oh good grief I guess the OP did clarify that they are ints.

Comment: The biggest issue with this approach is that by adding another column they will have two copies of the same information. This is a terrible idea. Consider what happens on an update. This is why composite keys exist.

Comment: Thank you @ThomasDoconski. I'll have to explain the composite key again. I hope my employer understand me and accepts. if won't I guess I'll have to apply Thomas' solution. And yes, I agree with you Sean Lange. This is a terrible idea and creates unnecessary data duplication.

Comment: @SeanLange I agree with you. That would create data chaos.

Comment: Although I don't believe the solution I wrote the best practice, I believe now it covers the INT issue. I hope you can convince the PO @haein